# Rails 4 simple_format, changing tag wrapper removes line breaks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

In Rails 4 I want to display text in a view whilst preserving the line breaks. Using simple_format, I can do this, but it wraps the whole thing in p tags which I don't want.

If I use the following code, it changes the wrapper to a div, but does not then preserve the line breaks. Is there another way I can do this?

```
<dt>Details</dt>
    <dd><%= simple_format(@enquiry.details, {}, wrapper_tag: "div") %></dd>
```

The above code wraps each new line in div tags.

Essentially I would like to display my line breaks but without being forced to use p tags.

Thanks

Comment: I just ended up using a gsub for now, and not simple_format:

    gsub("\n", "<br />").html_safe

Comment: Careful - `simple_format` sanitizes input by default. The solution you went with does not and is dangerous if you're rendering user input.